# We're building Windows VMs from ISO, on VSphere. What are my automation options?

Tags: windows, virtualization, automation

We're an old-school Windows software shop, with a large legacy install base, running both client and server applications on various versions of Windows. As you might imagine, our testing matrix is huge, and in constant need of updating.

We routinely build (or update) a number of Windows template VMs on VSphere/VMWare. I'm looking for a way to automate these builds, starting from a bare VM and a Windows ISO.

I see that [Packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-iso.html) has a "vmware-iso" builder, which depends on Vagrant. Any other options available?

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to automate. Have you considered Windows Deployment Toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following procedure as an alternative to Packer:

•    Choose host, cluster, or datacenter in the vSphere Web Client inventory.

•    Click the Virtual Machines tab and right-click and select All vCenter Actions > Guest OS > Install/Upgrade VMware Tools.

•    Add information about the installation or upgrade configuration.

•    For including MSI arguments or excluding VMware tools during the installation process, add arguments to the setup.exe command in the Advanced Options text box.

Command to add MSI arguments: `setup.exe /S /v ""/qn msi_args""`

Command to exclude VMware Tools component: `setup.exe /S /v ""/qn msi_args ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=component""`